# Multiple Remote Desktop environments on one server without having to login

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm looking for a method of hosting multiple remote desktop environments without me having to enter different usernames and password everytime I connect.

I am aware you can save login credentials with an RDP file, and you it will work as long as the server address is somewhat different. In theory, you can make multiple port mappings to the same port in the router, and use that with multiple RDP files to have it working, but this does not work inside a lan. I don't have a DNS server in my lan either.

I need the Smart Sizing feature so using the Remote desktop Connection manager is also not an option, unless there's a version that supports this. I'm using an old version.

I prefer not to use something hacked together (autoit script that launches an rdp file, and sends keystrokes to the login prompt) but if there's a commandline switch available to provide username and password info and it can be made into a shortcut, that is acceptable.

So... How can I setup that I have multiple RDP connections to the same server (currently running Windows 10, with hack allowing multiple RDP connections), and connect to them without entering a username and password?

Comment: RD-Connection supports Smart Sizing now. https://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/smart-sizing-exposed-in-remote-desktop-ui,-at-last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to user RDCman to manage all the RD connection settings and logon credentials. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion a while ago, and completely forgot I made this question because there were little response back then. So a +1 and accept from me. :)